# method does not override or implement a method from a supertype (:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac)

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I am getting the following error While running command react-native run-android. What could be the problem?

> :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavacC:\Users\Deeksha
>   Gupta\git\pe-gold-native\android\app\src\main\java\com\pegoldnative\MainActivity.java:39:
>   error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   @Override ^ 1 error FAILED
>        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

**MainActivity.java**

```
  package com.pegoldnative;

  import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
  import com.horcrux.svg.RNSvgPackage;
  import io.realm.react.RealmReactPackage;
  import com.brentvatne.react.ReactVideoPackage;
  import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
  import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;

  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.List;
  import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
  import com.mihir.react.tts.*;
  import com.rnfs.RNFSPackage;
  public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

/**
 * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
 * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
 */
     @Override
     protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "pegoldnative";
     }

/**
 * Returns whether dev mode should be enabled.
 * This enables e.g. the dev menu.
 */
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
         return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

/**
 * A list of packages used by the app. If the app uses additional views
 * or modules besides the default ones, add more packages here.
 */
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
         return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
             new MainReactPackage(),
             new RNSvgPackage(),
             new RealmReactPackage(),
             new ReactVideoPackage()
             , new VectorIconsPackage()
            , new RCTTextToSpeechModule()
            , new RNFSPackage()
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your code too

Comment: the function at line number 39 you are trying to override is not available to override, you can post the code and give us more insights!

Answer (score 3):

By the date you posted this question I believe you are using `react native 0.29` or above.

If so, in `react native 0.29` the way it bootstrap the packages have changed:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.29.0

Now you have a `MainApplication.java` class, wich extends `Application` and implements `ReactApplication`.

There you can override `getUseDeveloperSupport()` method.

MainApplication.java

```
package com.yourapp;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(          
          new MainReactPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
      return mReactNativeHost;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, I did the changes according to  new version of RN

Comment: I had this problem when I upgraded my react-native from `27.0` to `35.0`; that was an empty project though...!!